# Where is "combine hsv" in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Blender 2.93.2, I can find the "combine RGB" Geometry Node but I cannot find the "combine HSV" Geometry Node. Where is it hiding?

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) correctly pointed out that I missed the *Geometry* in the question.  As they say in their comment on the question: there isn't (yet) a geometry Combine HSV node.

As to the *Shader* Combine HSV node: It's hiding in converters, where it always hides:

[image: add node menu showing Combine HSV]

You can always enter HSV in the search bar to find it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own, using math nodes... and ColorRamp:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like the color-ramp to avoid the math .. :)